# No Result in Query Has Declared Variables

Tags: sql-server

I created a multiple database join query. Normally query works. But I need to improve my query. And I decided to use variables. I am not expert using variables in sql-server.

When I execute this query, there is no result. Only **"Command(s) completed successfully."**

What should I do ?

```
DECLARE @SoldQuantity INT;
DECLARE @InvoiceCount INT;
DECLARE @Stock DECIMAL;
DECLARE @StockCode NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @StockName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Unit NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SalePrice DECIMAL;

SELECT
    @StockCode = p.StockCode,
    @StockName = p.Name,
    @Unit = p.Unit,
    @SalePrice = MAX(p.SalePrice),
    @SoldQuantity = COALESCE(SUM(d.Quantity), 0),
    @InvoiceCount = COUNT(DISTINCT d.InvoiceId),
    @Stock = (
        select SUM(ISNULL(ENVANTER, 0)) as ENVANTER 
        FROM B_DB.dbo.F0101D0002TBLDEPOENVANTER 
        WHERE DEPO = 101 AND STOKNO = p.ProductId 
    ) 
FROM A_DB.dbo.InvoiceDetails as d 
    LEFT JOIN A_DB.dbo.Products as p ON p.ProductId = d.ProductId
WHERE d.InvoiceId IN (
    select Id from A_DB.dbo.Invoices 
    WHERE Canceled = 0 AND Returned = 0 AND Branch = 'BRANCH_A' 
        AND CreatedAt >= '2018-01-05' AND CreatedAt< '2018-04-05') AND d.Canceled = 0 
        AND p.ProductId NOT IN (select ProductId from A_DB.dbo.Products WHERE CreatedAt >= '2018-01-05' AND CreatedAt < '2018-04-05')
GROUP BY p.ProductId, p.StockCode, p.Name, p.Unit
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.InvoiceId) < 10
AND @Stock > @SoldQuantity
```

**UPDATE**

This query works fine. But In Having clause i'm repeating myself. I'm asking is there any way not to repeat my self.

```
SELECT
    p.StockCode,
    p.Name,
    p.Unit,
    MAX(p.SalePrice),
    COALESCE(SUM(d.Quantity), 0) as SoldQuantity,
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.InvoiceId) as InvoiceCount,
    (
        select SUM(ISNULL(ENVANTER, 0)) as ENVANTER 
        FROM B_DB.dbo.F0101D0002TBLDEPOENVANTER 
        WHERE DEPO = 101 AND STOKNO = p.ProductId 
    ) as Stock
FROM A_DB.dbo.InvoiceDetails as d 
    LEFT JOIN A_DB.dbo.Products as p ON p.ProductId = d.ProductId
WHERE d.InvoiceId IN (
    select Id from A_DB.dbo.Invoices 
    WHERE Canceled = 0 AND Returned = 0 AND Branch = 'BRANCH_A' 
        AND CreatedAt >= '2018-01-05' AND CreatedAt< '2018-04-05') AND d.Canceled = 0 
        AND p.ProductId NOT IN (select ProductId from A_DB.dbo.Products WHERE CreatedAt >= '2018-01-05' AND CreatedAt < '2018-04-05')
GROUP BY p.ProductId, p.StockCode, p.Name, p.Unit
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.InvoiceId) < 10
AND (select SUM(ISNULL(ENVANTER, 0)) as ENVANTER 
        FROM B_DB.dbo.F0101D0002TBLDEPOENVANTER 
        WHERE DEPO = 101 AND STOKNO = p.ProductId ) > COALESCE(SUM(d.Quantity), 0)
```

Comment: That's what you should be expecting. Assigning values to a variable in a `SELECT` statement doesn't produce a resultset output. Take, for example, the simple query: `DECLARE @i int; SELECT @i = 1;` This won't return a resultset output, you would need to do `SELECT @i;`

Comment: i also tried SELECT @StockCode at the bottom of query. But i have only single row. Not rows. How can i transform it to a result set ?

Comment: Also, you are assigning a value to the variables `@Stock` and `@SoldQuantity` in the same statement you are using them your `HAVING` clause. Is that intentional? If neither `@Stock` or `@SoldQuantity`  have an assigned value prior to that, the clause will evaluate to `NULL > NULL`; which is always FALSE.

Comment: If you want a result set, don't assign values to a variable. A variable can only hold **1 value** (excluding Table Variables, but I don't recommend their use).

Comment: ok. 1 value. And what should i do ?  Should i repeat myself writing again subqueries instead of writing variables (@Stock > @SoldQuantity) in having clause

Comment: I know you said you're trying to improve your query, but what are you trying to improve? Why did you introduce the variables in the first place?

Comment: @EricBrandt I wrote the query without variables. And i repeated myself. I wrote two times. And query looks massy. And i wanted to use variables option. After doing this I will improve query. But i failed. Because variables hold only single values. Not a set. But i want to learn is there any way not to repeat myself.

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat"? If you mean the subquery then yes, have a look at my answer. You can't reference the alias of a column in the `HAVING` clause, so you'll still need to use the `SUM`. I also recommend against `COALESCE` in that clause as well; it'll make the query non-SARGable.

Answer (score 1):

When assigning values to variables, no output result set will be given. For example, take the simple statement below:

```
DECLARE @i int;
SELECT @i = 1;
```

On it's own, this won't return a resultset. You'll need to use a further `SELECT` statement to return the value of `@i`:

```
DECLARE @i int;
SELECT @i = 1;
SELECT @i AS i;
```

In seems, also, that you're under the impression that variables can hold multiple values, this is wrong. A variable can only have 1 value. So, let's expand the above a little:

```
DECLARE @i int;
SELECT @i = i
FROM (VALUES (1),(2)) V(i);
SELECT @i AS i;
```

Notice that `@i` has a value of `2`.

It seems, however, that you don't actually need to to assign the values of your variables in your `SELECT` as you want a result set, and you're under the impression you can set the value of a variable in the `SELECT` and use it in the `HAVING` (wrong). This, therefore, might be what you're after:

```
SELECT
    p.StockCode,
    p.Name,
    p.Unit,
    MAX(p.SalePrice),
    COALESCE(SUM(d.Quantity), 0),
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.InvoiceId),
    s.ENVANTER AS Stock
FROM A_DB.dbo.InvoiceDetails as d 
    LEFT JOIN A_DB.dbo.Products as p ON p.ProductId = d.ProductId
    CROSS APPLY (
        select SUM(ISNULL(ENVANTER, 0)) as ENVANTER 
        FROM B_DB.dbo.F0101D0002TBLDEPOENVANTER 
        WHERE DEPO = 101 AND STOKNO = p.ProductId 
    ) Stock s
WHERE d.InvoiceId IN (
    select Id from A_DB.dbo.Invoices 
    WHERE Canceled = 0 AND Returned = 0 AND Branch = 'BRANCH_A' 
        AND CreatedAt >= '2018-01-05' AND CreatedAt< '2018-04-05') AND d.Canceled = 0 
        AND p.ProductId NOT IN (select ProductId from A_DB.dbo.Products WHERE CreatedAt >= '2018-01-05' AND CreatedAt < '2018-04-05')
GROUP BY p.ProductId, p.StockCode, p.Name, p.Unit, s.ENVANTER
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.InvoiceId) < 10
AND s.ENVANTER > SUM(d.Quantity);
```

This, however, is **untested** (as I can't test it without data, if you get an error, you'll need to troubleshoot). The query can likely be simplified (as there's a few subqueries in subqueries), however, without further understanding I've left your query pretty much as it was. The variables have been removed, and the `HAVING` clause has been changed. I've also moved the subquery in the `SELECT` to a `CROSS APPLY`.